# Compiling example program supplied by itext

Tags: java, xml, pdf, itext, xfa

http://itextsupport.com/download/xfaworker.html

I have downloaded iText example program and try to test it on my computer.  Want to test that i can flattern the XFA form I have created using PDFBox library provided by Apache.  I want to flatten my PDF so they can be joined into one pdf file.  Below is list of all the files i thought was required for compiling.  Most was obtained by following instructions from above url.

```
10/02/2015  05:15 PM    <DIR>          ..
23/02/2014  03:34 AM            10,114 antlr4-annotations-4.2.jar
23/02/2014  03:34 AM           327,041 antlr4-runtime-4.2.jar
23/04/2013  11:17 PM             2,199 FillAndFlatten.java
10/02/2015  05:15 PM               358 flatten.bat
16/05/2014  06:05 AM            24,193 itext-licensekey-1.0.3.jar
16/12/2014  08:53 AM            62,418 itext-pdfa-5.5.4.jar
16/12/2014  08:53 AM            97,001 itext-xtra-5.5.4.jar
09/02/2015  03:04 PM             2,226 itextkey.xml
16/12/2014  08:53 AM         2,148,390 itextpdf-5.5.4.jar
06/06/2014  10:41 PM             1,606 LICENSE-abego.TXT
29/05/2014  01:12 AM             1,537 LICENSE-ANTLR.txt
21/09/2014  12:35 AM            17,099 LICENSE-rhino.txt
23/02/2014  03:34 AM            25,515 org.abego.treelayout.core-1.0.1.jar
01/01/2013  03:20 AM               725 README.txt
20/09/2014  11:12 PM         1,134,765 rhino-1.7R4.jar
17/12/2014  01:29 AM         2,230,720 xfaworker-5.5.4.jar
25/05/2012  08:22 PM            27,624 xfa_data.xml
25/05/2012  08:22 PM            80,248 xfa_form.pdf
```

When i run the flatten.bat file this is output i get

```
C:\Users\jason.STERLINGSYSTEMS\Downloads\flatterner>C:\jdk1.8.0_25x64\bin\javac
-cp "itextpdf-5.5.4.jar;xmlworker-5.5.4.jar;xfaworker-5.5.4.jar;itext-licensekey
-1.0.3.jar" FillAndFlatten.java
FillAndFlatten.java:46: error: cannot access CssAppliers
        XFAFlattener xfaf = new XFAFlattener(document, writer);
                            ^
  class file for com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.CssAppliers not found
FillAndFlatten.java:47: error: cannot access CssAppliersAware
        xfaf.flatten(new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray()));
            ^
  class file for com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.CssAppliersAware not found
2 errors

C:\Users\jason.STERLINGSYSTEMS\Downloads\flatterner>java -cp ".;itextpdf-5.5.4.j
ar;xmlworker-5.5.4.jar;xfaworker-5.5.4.jar;itext-licensekey-1.0.3.jar;antlr4-run
time-4.2.jar;antlr4-annotations-4.2.jar;org.abego.treelayout.core-1.0.1.jar;rhin
o-1.7R4.jar" FillAndFlatten
Error: Could not find or load main class FillAndFlatten
```

So the question is why am i getting 2 errors?  To me it looks like i am missing some libraries.  Given i have followed their instructions not too sure what i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `xmlworker.jar` to your directory `flatterner`. This file contains the  class `com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.CssAppliersAware`.

Comment: The OP's command line seems to indicate that he already has added `xmlworker-5.5.4.jar` to the classpath.

Comment: @mkl The filename is added to the classpath. But it is missing in the directory.